# Formato de fechas sql server 2012

Tags: sql-server

Cuando ingresos dos fechas para comprobar los datos que están entre los dos valores de fechas, depende del formato que le doy, asi es la cantidad de datos que me devuelve. ¿Por qué sucede esto? Formatos que he utilizado: (2019/05/07) y (07/05/2019) 
(WHERE T.Date BETWEEN @FechaIni AND @FechaFin)

Comment: que tipo de dato estas usando para almacenar las fechas?

Comment: Bienvenido Daniel, si bien tu regunta está clara, sería bueno que nos muestres algo de código para poder ayudarte... Date una vuelta por [ask] para más información. De paso podes hacer un [tour] para ganar tu primera medalla.

Comment: Estoy usando DATETIME amigo. Victor, básicamente esta es la porción de código: SELECT TOP 1 [Sales Staff] 
     FROM DBTIENDA.dbo.[FASANI$Trans_ Sales Entry] T with(nolock)
     WHERE T.[Store No_]=H.[Store No_] AND 
       T.[POS Terminal No_]=H.[POS Terminal No_] AND
       T.[Transaction No_]=H.[Transaction No_])[Staff],
    H.[Store No_]
  FROM [DBTIENDA].dbo.[FASANI$Transaction Header] H with(nolock)
  WHERE (H.Date BETWEEN @FechaIni AND @FechaFin) justo aqui comparo las fechas

Answer (score 2):

Debes de entender que el formato de las fechas es sólo la forma que tenemos de representar el valor y según las configuraciones establecidas será la forma en que se interprete. Internamente, un valor `DATETIME` se almacena como 2 enteros, uno para la fecha y otro para el tiempo. SQL Server por default utiliza un formato `mm/dd/yyyy` que es lo común en EEUU, pero en gran parte del mundo se utiliza `dd/mm/yyyy`. Por lo cual, la interpretación puede variar.

Como consejo general, siempre se deberían de usar los formatos ISO que no dependen de configuraciones. Estos son `YYYYMMDD` o `YYYY-MM-DDThh:mi:ss.mss`.

En tu caso en particular, cuando envías el año al final la fecha se interpreta como 5 de julio, pero cuando se envía al inicio se interpreta como 7 de mayo. Puedes hacer la prueba de la siguiente forma:

```
SELECT CAST( '2019/05/07' AS datetime), CAST( '07/05/2019' AS datetime)
```

También puedes ver como cambia cambiando el valor usando `SET LANGUAGE 'English'` o algún otro idioma de `sys.syslanguages`.